# LINQ to Entities emulating SQL "IN" acting an int[]

Tags: int, linq-to-entities

OK...been looking at most of the topics up here pertaining to L2E and something similar to the IN SQL operator, and while what I've seen as been educating, it's not getting me much closer to solving the problem.

I know that as of EF4, .Contains is available. Here's an example of one that I'm already using that works like a champ to filter based on a string array:

```
public static IQueryable<TblIssueDetail> FilterByIssueName(this IQueryable<TblIssueDetail> source, string[] issueName)
{
    if (null != issueName)
        source = issueName.Aggregate(source, (current, word) => current.Where(x => x.IssueName.Contains(word)));
    return source;
}
```

However, when I try a similar technique with an int[] it falls flat on its face.

```
public static IQueryable<TblIssueDetail> FilterByProviderAffected(this IQueryable<TblIssueDetail> source, int[] providerAffected)
{
    if (null != providerAffected)
        source = providerAffected.Aggregate(source,
                                            (current, item) =>
                                            current.Where(x => x.ProviderAffected.Equals(item)));
    return source;
}
```

What I'm receiving when debugging is: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context." when I hit the filter with the int[] in it.

Am I just missing something silly and obvious, or am I way, way off base on this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call `.Contains` rather than `.Equals`.

Comment: I'd really, really like to...except .Contains is not available off of x.ProviderAffected, presumably because it's an `int`. Oh, how I wish it were that easy!

Comment: @rca: You need check whether the array `Contains` the `int`.  However, I don't think EF can do that, so you'll need to do it on the client.

Comment: Nope...tried reversing my logic, which gave me the `.Contains` option off of the `int[] providerAffected` variable, but then it started complaining about not being able to infer the type from the usage. `public static IQueryable<TblIssueDetail> FilterByProviderAffected(this IQueryable<TblIssueDetail> source, int[] providerAffected)
{
    if (null != providerAffected)
        source = providerAffected.Aggregate(source, (current, item) => current.Where(providerAffected.Contains(item)));
    return source;
}`

Comment: @rca: You still need to pass a lambda expression to `Where`.

Comment: I'm completely missing it. I'm assuming your talking a lambda within the `current.Where()` section, but I'm at a loss what to put there. It looks like `item` is containing the current value of the `int[] providerAffected` but I'm not sure what structure I need to move forward.

Comment: `x => item.Contains(x.ProviderAffected)`

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer, but now it's not happy because the 'item' is an `int` instead of an `IQueryable<int?>` and doesn't appear to support any explicit or implicit casting that I can think of. This is the last thing standing between me and project completion, and I'm denting my monitor from beating my head against it. Thanks for all your help...I certainly appreciate it!

Comment: @SLaks I appreciate your help, but I'm still stuck. Do you have any other suggestions that might get me back on track? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try calling `AsQueryable()`.  However, I'm not sure if it will help; I don't think EF can do this on the server.